# Docusign API -- is it possibly to retrieve UserName by email OR by Docusign UserID?

Tags: docusignapi

I've successfully retrieved DocuSign "UserID"s by email (using CheckAccountMember).  However, I see no way to retrieve a DocuSign "User Name" (which I need to pass to GetFolderItems for a project I'm working on).  Is there a call I can make that I haven't run across yet? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Are these for user's on your account? If so you can do a `GET /account/{accountId}/users` and compare your responses. Or you could look up each user individually by adding the `{userId}` after `users/`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your response.  Yes, for user's on our account.  However, I neglected to mention I'm using SOAP and I can't seem to find anything that returns the "User Name".

Comment: Think i just found it... GetMembershipSummary.  will get back to you :-)

Comment: Good call. Sorry I assume most people use REST while setting up new workflows. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've found the corresponding SOAP API call, posting full answer for the benefit of the community:

If using DocuSign's SOAP API you need to make the **GetMembershipSummary** call. Notes about this call-

1. This is reserved for DocuSign use and you must have DocuSign Administrator rights to use this method.
2. This method requests a list of summary information about the accounts and users associated with the supplied email address.

A sample call looks similar to this:

```
POST /api/3.0/accountmanagement.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: docusign.net
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.docusign.net/API/AccountManagement/GetMembershipSummary"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetMembershipSummary xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/AccountManagement">
      <Email>string</Email>
    </GetMembershipSummary>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Otherwise, if using DocuSign's REST API you can make the **Get User Information** API call:

URL:
*/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}*

Optional query string: additional_info={true/false}

Sample Call:

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Ergin, thanks... i was waiting to hear back from EnterpriseSupport because I see this call is "reserved for DocuSign use and you must have DocuSign Administrator rights to use this method".  Is there an alternative method to retrieve "User Name"?

Comment: Hi Kerrie, I think when it says DocuSign Administrator rights all that means is that you need to be an Administrator in your account.  By default you are the admin of your developer sandbox account that you created so you should be able to access this.

Comment: Thanks Ergin. We were attempting to use this method in our production environment.  I heard back from Enterprise Support.  They confirmed that this method is reserved for DocuSign use only???  Waiting to hear back from Professional Services now.  Will post a solution when I find one.